# Getting Type string is not assignable to type string for TS component in Storybook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I have a menu component that receives a single prop `linkColor` as a string to control the CSS color value of the icon and text.

I just switched everything over to TypeScript and everything is working except my Storybook implementation.

The specific error I'm getting is: `Type '{ linkColor: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)` on the component despite the prop having an inline type definition. I've tried passing the prop as an arg, passing in `typeof` definitions to the whole component and nothing works.

My Menu Component

```
const SettingsMenu = (linkColor: string) => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)

    return (
        <div className={`self-start ml-5 pb-2 paragraph-small font-medium ${linkColor}`}>
            <button className="flex items-center" onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>
                <Settings className="mr-3" />
                <span className="inline-block">{'Settings'}</span>
            </button>
            <SlideOut title="Settings" menuData={data} isOpen={isOpen} setIsOpen={setIsOpen} />
        </div>
    )
}

export { SettingsMenu }
```

My Storybook Story

```
import { SettingsMenu } from '../SettingsMenu'

export default {
    title: 'Settings Menu',
    component: SettingsMenu,
}

export const Primary = () => <SettingsMenu linkColor="text-black" />
// This is the line that's throwing the error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't access the value of react component every value that passes as a prop is in the `props` object either you access it like `props.linkColor` or destruct it and define its types as well, that's why you can't access `linkColor` value in `.jsx` or in `.tsx`

```
interface SettingsMenuType {
  linkColor: string;
}

const SettingsMenu: React.FC<SettingsMenuType> = ({linkColor}) => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)

    return (
        <div className={`self-start ml-5 pb-2 paragraph-small font-medium ${linkColor}`}>
            <button className="flex items-center" onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>
                <Settings className="mr-3" />
                <span className="inline-block">{'Settings'}</span>
            </button>
            <SlideOut title="Settings" menuData={data} isOpen={isOpen} setIsOpen={setIsOpen} />
        </div>
    )
}

export { SettingsMenu }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your component props type is invalid.

Please define props type and use like the following.

```
interface SettingsMenuProps{
   linkColor: string;
}
const SettingsMenu = ({linkColor}: SettingsMenuProps) => {
....
}
```